# What algorithm should I use to make a dynamic Line following robot?

Tags: pid, wheeled-robot

I want to make a LFR using IR sensor.
Till now I coded my robot according to the track I am going to participate in. So it won't work on any other track.
But now I want to code it in a way that it will work on almost any track with any design.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* MomshadDinury, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Generally speaking, you use the IR sensor to return a measurably different value when it's on the line. You run forward while the sensor detects the line, and when it stops detecting the line you enter a "search" routine that rotates the robot until the line is found, and the process repeats. If you would like to *discuss this in more detail*, please join us in [chat]!

Comment: Search routine? U mean user define function?

Comment: I mean turn left, turn right, etc., until the line is found.